# What is the best way to mask an UI Event?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-interface

I am working with a DataGridView, and I use the `CellValueChanged` event.

I dont want this event to be triggered when I change a cell value by the code. However, I want it to be triggered when the user edits it.

That's why I enclose my cell value change operations with the following code :

```
void changeCellOperation()
{
    dgv.CellValueChanged -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellValueChanged);

    ...
    cell.Value = myNewCellValue
    ...

    dgv.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellValueChanged);
}
```

I ended to have several differents functions where my DataGridView cells are updated this way.

Because these functions are called from different places and can be nested, I cannot afford to keep this code as is to avoid event unwanted event reactivation.

So I ended up this way :

```
int valueChangedEventMask = 0;

void changeCellOperation()
{
    valueChangedEventMask++;

    ...
    cell.Value = myNewCellValue
    ...

    valueChangedEventMask--;
}

void dgv_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (valueChangedEventMask > 0)
        return

    ...
}
```

This works fine. Also when the calls are nested, including inside the event itself.

But the `CellValueChanged` event is now **fired too many times for no reasons**.

Because I often have to cope with this pattern, I am looking for a solution that can be applicable generally for Events in UIs, not only the DataGridView.

So my question is:

What is the best tip to mask UI Events correctly and avoid unnecessary Events fires ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Differentiating between events raised by user interaction and my own code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729897/differentiating-between-events-raised-by-user-interaction-and-my-own-code)

Comment: Something like [CellBeginEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellbeginedit(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'm sorry the linked question does unfortunately answer mine. I cannot use CellBeginEdit: it triggers immediately as the user starts to type in a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up mixing both solutions in a very simple one. I use a counter and I only hook/unhook the events I want to mask.

```
EventMask valueChangedEventMask;

// In the class constructor
valueChangedEventMask = new EventMask(
    () => { dgv.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellValueChanged); },
    () => { dgv.CellValueChanged -= new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dgv_CellValueChanged); }
);

// The value change operation I want to hide from the event
void changeCellOperation()
{
    valueChangedEventMask.Push();

    ...
    cell.Value = myNewCellValue
    ...

    valueChangedEventMask.Pop();
}

// The class
public class EventMask
{
    Action hook;
    Action unHook;

    int count = 0;

    public EventMask(Action hook, Action unHook)
    {
        this.hook = hook;
        this.unHook = unHook;
    }

    public void Push()
    {
        count++;
        if (count == 1)
            unHook();
    }

    public void Pop()
    {
        count--;
        if (count == 0)
            hook();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`CellValueChanged` is not an UI event, but a property changed event. That means you can not use it to distinguish user input from programmatic change. You can always use subscriber/unsucscribe or flag+/- or BeginEdit/EndEdit-similar technique, but maybe you have to find another (better) approach. To example, in case of checkbox you can use `Click` event instead of `Changed`, because (surprise!) it will tell you when the user click it and otherwise safely change value of `Checked` programmatically.

In case of `DataGridView` easiest would be to use `Changed` with some flag (which will be set when edit begins and reset when ends - see, `CellBeginEdit/CellEndEdit` ).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `CellEndEdit` instead of `CellValueChange`. I don't know what your method `dgv_CellValueChanged` does, just be careful that `CellEndEdit` is fired every time you exit the edit mode for the cell, even if its value has not been changed. This means that you have to keep trace of the current values of your cells if you don't want the method to be executed when the value doesn't change.

I would avoid events related with the mouse such as CellClick because your users could use just the keyboard.

Anyway I usually avoid this kind of problems by separating the logic from the user interface, i.e. I write a separate class which is bound to the form. Take a look at [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) (you can implement your own version in WinForms if you want) or the good old [MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.This is a fully "manual" DataGridView. There is no datasource nor databinding mechnism bound to it. I will try what you suggest with CellEndEdit.

Comment: What I mean is that if I haven't got a data binding mechanism I build it by myself. It's more code to write, but I think it's worth the effort, especially if you develop your own framework that can be used across many different projects

Comment: Agreed. My requirements are that some cells needs specific colors depending on their values, some cells toggles from/to readonly mode, other cells are calculated values, plus the grid itself is transposed so a column is a row in my data model... The logic is pretty complicated and I am forced to design and fill my grid manually. I have to confess it is more pleasant than it seems, and it can be achieved very cleanly. I even discover some resuable pieces of code. I dont think 3d party component would require less work. Rediscovering the DataGridView this way make me feel like coding in Excel :)